# Are C++ style const references allowed/working in ObjC++?

Tags: c++, objective-c

Consider (File.mm)

```
enum SomeEnum {
    e1, e2
} ;

@interface SO : NSObject 

- (void) dealWithConstCppRefEnum: (const SomeEnum&) someEnum ;

@end

struct CPPObj {
    void doToObjCObj(SO * obj) {
        [obj dealWithConstCppRefEnum:e1] ;
    }
}

@implementation SO

- (void) dealWithConstCppRefEnum: (const SomeEnum&) someEnum {
    if (someEnum == e1) {
        //
    } else if (someEnum == e2) {
        //
    } else {
        NSLog(@"WTF??") ;
    }
}

@end
```

(This is a simplified version of what I am struggling with)

I always get: "WTF??"

Anyone knows how to reconcile C++ style const references with C/ObjC inside an ObjC++ file?

Comment: can you output "someEnum" to log? :)

Comment: Yep. some gibberish like: 668297068 which looks like an address, not a value ...

Comment: and this is ok for address of enum structure ;)

Comment: Tried it and it works on my side, are you sure the example is right ? On another note, why pass enum as const-ref, this is POD anyway.

Comment: Got to interface with "std" C++ that is cross-platform (don't ask, please) and I get a const someStuffOrOther& foo as a C++ argument that I want to pass down to my ObjC implementation ...

Comment: All I know is const-ref C++ obj works well in ObjC++ so the problem is likely elsewhere. Since the example does not really show the problem, it will be hard to help you. Is operator== well defined for someStuffOrOther type ?

Comment: In the simplest case I am dealing with, someStuffOrOther is an enum ... and I get hair pulling odd values (which really look like addresses, but what do I know?) when I expect values between 0 and 4 ...

Comment: This should work fine. You may have another bug in your real code.