# Does the concept of "const reference" in C++ exists in Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, reference, constants

I'm concern about reference and I would to avoid the maximum of copy of object when I call methods in Objective-C.

Some people says that Objective-C passes object by-value, so does this C++ is still possible in Objective-C? Or would a workaround exist?

For the moment the only solution that I see would be to use Objective-C++.

Comment: Fyi, C++ also passed all objects by value.  When passing a reference, the value of the reference is passed.

Comment: @RichardCritten Not really, references are not objects, so you cannot copy them or pass them by value, strictly speaking.

Comment: I don't know if Objective-C has reference-to-const ... but it certainly has const and pointers.  So a workround is pointer-to-const.

Comment: @MartinBonner In Objective-C constness of objects isn't provided by the language, but by the class system. So it is simply reference to an instance of a constant type.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Of course you can copy references and pass them by value. This is nothing restricted to objects (in the sense of OOP).

Comment: So `void myFunction(const MyType& x);` would be the same as `-(void) myFunction:(nonnull const MyType *) x;` right?

Comment: Likely. However, nobody would care about that type decorations and simply write `-(void)myMethod:(MyType*)x`. Please take into account that there aren't  method calls in Objective-C, but dynamic dispatching. This makes such "optimizations" meaningless in Objective-C. To make a long story short: Objective-C is a completely different language because of its completely different type system.

Comment: I found an way of doing this here [const ref in Objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552856/are-c-style-const-references-allowed-working-in-objc). Simply as `-(void) myFunction:(const MyType&) x;` I don't know why this is not really referred on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective-C all objects are created on heap. Therefore all objects are referenced. Therefore no object is "silently" copied, especially not when passed to a method or function:

```
NSString *foo = @"bar"; // foo is a reference to a string object
doSomething( foo ); // a reference is passed
```

Objective-C passes arguments always by-value as C does, but since it is always a reference, the reference is copied (usually a machine word) not touching the identity of the referred object.

```
void doSomething( NSMutableString* foo ) // A function taking a reference to an instance of NSMutableString
{
  [foo appendString:@"foobar"];
  foo = nil;
}

NSMutableString *foo = [@"bar" mutableCopy]; // foo is a reference to an instance of NSMutableString
doSomething( foo ); // A copy of the reference, nor the object neither a copy of the object is passed
// foo is unchanged, since it is copied through pass by value.
// the object, foo points to, is @"barfoobar", since the object is not copied
```

So there is simply nothing to avoid.